# Open email Activity and get result?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

I am using an intent to open an Activity and allow the user to send an email.
Is it possible to be notified of the result after the user is done with this activity?

Fro example be notified that email was sent, or cancel was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is specified for any of the intents regarding email or text messaging and the like.

You can't be sure which Activity will end up handling your intent, and each Activity could return different resultCodes for the same logical outcome.

In my testing the text messaging app in the emulator returned zero no matter the outcome.

Answer is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209649/email-which-are-intent-action-send-return-values)

Answer (score 2):

There are several similar questions, like these ones :

[Toast after e-mail been sent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814661/toast-after-e-mail-been-sent-in-android)

[Get Mail Sent Notification in onActivityResult "Android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600149/get-mail-sent-notification-in-onactivityresult-android)

And it doesn't look possible at all.